# Query and pivot unique values in one step from 2 column table in google sheets with a formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have data in two colums in a spreadsheet representing variables/values from different individuals/entries. Not every individual has the same variables but generally different entries are separated by one or two rows.

My goal would be to transpose unique values in A:A, then Query Column B to match each of the unique data entries that match a particular column header.

I will share  my answer which utilizes two steps and a few different querys but would like to know if a single formula can accomplish this by consolidating into 1 or 2 formulas?

Sample  data

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
|  |  |
| b | 4 |
| d | 5 |
|  |  |
| a | 3 |
| d | 4 |

Desired Output

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
|  | 4 | 5 |  |
| 3 |  |  | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=bycol(unique(torow(A:A,1),1),lambda(z,{z;filter(B:B,A:A=z)}))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks a bit different than desired output where there ar e three rows of output (not including the header)

Comment: I was working off your `transpose + query` formulas which provides similar results (https://i.imgur.com/0GGogv9.png) but with another blank row (row 2).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the output I transpose unique values to column headers

```
TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")))
```

Then I replicate the following query to match the number of unique header values

```
IFERROR(QUERY($A$1:$B,"SELECT B WHERE A = '"&$C1&"'"),"")
```

The reason this is undesirable is because I then also have to replicate this for every additional unique header value (in above table it would require  IFERROR(QUERY...c1... Same for d1, e1,f1.

Can this all be done with one equation ?